# Transverse momentum of $W$ boson decay products

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak

[This paper on top-antitop events (ATLAS, 2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4314) states (page 11, 3rd paragraph) that

> Because of the $V$−$A$ structure of the $W$ boson decay, down-type jets have on average a lower $p_\mathrm{T}$ than up-type jets.

How can this statement be proved?

Comment: CP violation has been measured and is part of the mainstream standard model. I think the statement you quote is a qualitative "explanation" of the spectra seen in Monte Carlo events that model the data and allow to know the quark type in the model's data..